# Deployment fail for magento 2.3 for php version 7.1.22 and 7.2.10

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

When I am trying to upload the Magento 2 module for Magento 2.3 it will fail to check in PHP version 7.1.22 and 7.2.10. it will not give even any error, I have attached screenshot please check it. How to resolve this issue or how can I avoid this PHP version check(I will not give support to these two versions)

Any help appreciated resolving this issue

[image]

I have checked in both PHP version. It will enable production mode in my local environment but getting an above error while uploading at Magento marketplace.

Still not resolved my issue, also generated ticket in Magento. They are not giving any solution to this issue.
Any help appreciated a lot.

Comment: Have you tried running the command bin/magento setup:di:compile locally?

Comment: yes but locally I have PHP version 7.0.32 and it works fine in 7.0.32, when I select magneto version for deployment it will ask me to select all supported PHP version and then it will give errors in a different version

Comment: Magento 2.3 supports both php7.1 and php7.2 so if you tick that your extension provides support for it you will also need to check it on these php versions. I would suggest you switch to php 7.2 locally and try running bin/magento setup:di:compile as a first step.

Comment: Do I need test version in both PHP versions, in 7.1.22 and 7.2.10?

Comment: Matching the patch version number is probably not needed but checking on 7.1 and 7.2 would come recommended.

Comment: I have checked in both PHP versions, the only error of memory_limit exists, I increased memory limit then it works fine. It enabled production mode in both versions then why Magento technical review fails?